# R codes for Poisson fixed and random effect for claims data

Tags: r

I have claim frequency panel data for five years consisting of age,cc,make of car,age and gender of insured person and geographical area.I have run a Poisson regression to model the claim frequency in R. Now i want to test for a Poisson fixed and random effect in R. I have done some research work and found the related codes:fm <- glmer(Y ~ A + B + (1|Subject), family = poisson, data = pData) in lme4 package.How do i apply it in my context? Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to start by laying out how you have the data organized, i.e provide `str(pData)`.

Comment: My data set consists of 584 policyhoders. I have records on their claim frequencies during a period of 5 years(which years they had claims or had no claims). The predictors consists of age,gender of insured,make, cc and age if vehicle and geographical area. i have all organised in MS excel. I have imported my data set into R.How do i proceed as from here? @ IShouldBuyABoat

Comment: I gave a specific suggestion which so far you are not attending to.

Comment: I am confused about what you actually mean by str(pData) @ IShouldBuyABoat

Comment: Your dataframe is the argument to the function `str`. Output occurs. What could be simpler?